# Angular: update nested array of a ngrx-store state using Immutable.js

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, immutable.js, ngrx-store

I am trying to uploaded the State of one of my object but without success at the moment.
I want to update the Cart record with a new item every time the user click on `Add To Cart`.
This is my `ngrx-store` State:

```
export interface UserState extends Map<string, any> {
    user: User;
    cart: Cart;
    addedToCart: boolean;
}

/* Initial state of any user */
export const UserStateRecord = Record( {
    user: Map( {} ),
    cart: Map( {} ),
    addedToCart: false
} );
```

The cart model is as follows:

```
export class Cart {
    constructor(
        public created: string,
        public totalAmount: number,
        public items: List<Item>
    ) { }
}

export class Item {
    constructor(
        public quantity: number,
        public totalAmount: number,
        public product: Product
    ) {  }
}
```

When the user adds an item to its cart, an action of type ADD_TO_CART is dispatched.
If the item is already inside the cart, I need to update the quantity and the total price, otherwise I need to add a new item to the cart.

Following is the reducer switch case that I have written as of now:

```
case UserActions.ADD_TO_CART:
    const newItems = state.cart.items.map( item => {
        if ( item.product.id === payload.id ) {
            return Map( item ).merge( {
                'quantity': 1 + item.quantity,
                'totalAmount': item.totalAmount + ( item.totalAmount / item.quantity )
            } );
        } else {
            return item;
        }
    } );
    //CODE SHOULD BE ADDED HERE TO UPDATE THE STATE
    return state.merge( {
        addedToCart: true
    } ) as UserState;
```

**Q1**: `newItems` contains the new set of Items, but I do not know how can I merge them to the state. Do you know how?

**Q2**: Also, how can I add a new item in case it is not already in the cart?

**Q3**: I have to convert my item to a map (Map (item)) in order to use merge, but would be better to have already a Map for each item in the cart. Someone knows how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your above example is a bit confusing as you say that your models are normal classes but then in your state they show as `Map`s...

```
export const UserStateRecord = Record( {
    user: Map( {} ), // this disagrees with the User class!
    cart: Map( {} ), // this disagrees with the Cart class!
    addedToCart: false
} );
```

Assuming what you really mean is that the User and Cart class are also `Record`s like `UserState` and so inherit `Map` methods...

Something like this using `update` and `updateIn` should do the trick for the reducer switch case...

```
return state.merge({
  // immutably update items in cart, providing default empty items List if not existing
  cart: state.cart.updateIn(
    ['items'], // path
    List<Item>(), // default empty item list iof not existing
    (items: List<Item>) => items.update( // updater for existing items
      // find index of exsisting item
      state.cart.items.findIndex(item => item.product.id === payload.id),
      // the new item to add if index not found, assuming this is in payload as not shown above 
      payload.item, 
      // updater for existing item, lets stay immutable and just create a new Item instance with updated properties
      existing => new Item(existing.quantity + 1, 
                          existing.totalAmount + (existing.totalAmount / existing.quantity), // not sure what this is calculating but you had it in original
                          existing.product)                 
    )
  ),
  addedToCart: true
})
```

However your definition for Records seem off to me too, in order to compile the above and strongly type the Records, instead of using `class Cart extends Map<string, any>` I used the following trick of extending an instanciated `Record` containing your field's defaults, and explicitly declaring the property types for the accessors...

```
export class Cart extends Record({created: undefined, totalAmount: 0, items: List<Item>()}) {
  created: string
  totalAmount: number
  items: List<Item>
}

// omitting `user` as has no bearing on this question
export class UserState extends Record({cart: undefined, addedToCart: false}) {
  cart: Cart
  addedToCart: boolean
}

export const state = new UserState({cart: new Cart()})
```